# AzureAD: tenant-independent SAML

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying out tenant-independent SAML via an app that my company is
developing with AzureAD acting as the SAML IDP. When I try to test it against a test tenant, I get the
following error:

AADSTS65005: The application needs access to a service that your
organization Default Directory has not subscribed to. Please contact
your Administrator to review the configuration of your service
subscriptions.

I suppose the error is being displayed
against the test tenant. The test tenant has pay-as-you-go plan enabled
for Azure. Does it need to subscribe to any other services?